# Database Class Error - php

Tags: php, database, pdo

I am having a problem with a database class that I have created.
When I try and display the data that is in the table, no data shows, but it still passes the database->select().

```
<?php

class database {

private $DBhost  = "localhost";
private $DBuser  = "username";
private $DBpass  = "password";
private $DBname  = "database";

private $PDO    = null;
private $stmt   = null;

function __construct() {
  $this->PDO = new PDO("mysql:host=" . $this->DBhost . ";dbname=" . $this->DBname . ";charset=utf8", $this->DBuser, $this->DBpass);
}

function __destruct() {
  $this->PDO = null;
}

function select($query, $param = array()) {
  try {
    $this->stmt = $this->PDO->prepare($query);
    if (count($param) != 0) {
      $this->stmt->execute($param);
    } else {
      $this->stmt->execute();
    }
  } catch(Exception $ex) {
    $this->error($ex);
    return false;
  }
}



function resultset() {
  return $this->stmt->fetchAll();
}

function error($ex) {
  die('Something broke :(');
}
}
?>
```

I am trying to use this to display data in a html table, as shown on this next page.

```
<?php
include 'code/db.php';
$DB = new database();
?>
<html>
<head>
  <title>List</title>
</head>
<body>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>First Name</th>
    <th>Last Name</th>
    <th>Email</th>
    <th>Phone number</th>
    <th>Mobile number</th>
    <th>Address</th>
    <th>State</th>
    <th>Post Code</th>
    <th>Settings</th>
  </tr>
<?php
$DB->select('SELECT * FROM owners ORDER BY first_name, last_name');

while($line = $DB->resultset()) {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $line['first_name'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $line['last_name'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $line['email'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $line['phone_number'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $line['mobile_number'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $line['address'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $line['state'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $line['post_code'] . "</td>";
  echo '<td><a href="item-list?id=' . $line['id'] . '">Details</a><a href="edit-owner?id=' . $line['id'] . '"</a></td>';
  echo "</tr>";
}

?>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

If you could help me out with this that would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `fetchAll` in your `resultset` function. An entire array of selected values will be returned and stored in `$line`. You'd then have to iterate over it.

Change the function to:

```
function resultset() {
  return $this->stmt->fetch( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

PDO is already a database class, you don't need any other. Especially such a stateful one. You just dug yourself a huge pitfall with this useless class and soon you will fall in it.

So, just keep raw PDO:

```
<?php

$DBhost  = "localhost";
$DBuser  = "username";
$DBpass  = "password";
$DBname  = "database";

$dsn = "mysql:host=$DBhostdbname=$DBname;charset=utf8";
$PDO = new PDO($dsn, $DBuser, $DBpass);
$PDO->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

What you actually need is to separate your SQL from HTML. So, get all your data first an then use whatever template to output it.

```
<?php
include 'code/db.php';
$stm  = $PDO->query('SELECT * FROM owners ORDER BY first_name, last_name');
$data = $stm->fetchAll();
?>
<html>
<head>
  <title>List</title>
</head>
<body>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>First Name</th>
    <th>Last Name</th>
    <th>Email</th>
    <th>Phone number</th>
    <th>Mobile number</th>
    <th>Address</th>
    <th>State</th>
    <th>Post Code</th>
    <th>Settings</th>
  </tr>
<?php foreach($data as $line):?>
  <tr>
    <td><?=$line['first_name']?></td>
    <td><?=$line['last_name']?></td>
    <td>
      <a href="item-list?id=<?=$line['id']?>">Details</a>
      <a href="edit-owner?id=<?=$line['id']?>Owner</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
<?php endforeach ?>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What happens when his database password changes? Although I agree that creating all these silly functions to wrap PDO functions hurts more than it helps (and I have devs who do this, usually those who don't understand _why_ PDO functions do what they do) I do agree with the OP that a small PDO wrapper class can be beneficial. Especially when classes (and thus passwords) are kept outside the `public_html` directory.

Comment: 1. I don't understand your question on password. 2. I don't understand your statement on beneficial wrapper.

Comment: I was pointing out the benefits of having a PDO wrapper class. For one thing, we can change the password without using Perl to change the text in hundreds or thousands of files.

Comment: I still can't get your idea. Why would we want to? Can't we store database credentials in a separate file without having a class?

Comment: You could, but what is that file then? I find it much simpler to store my classes outside the web root (there is not need for them to be publicly-accessible) and to store the information that they need in the class itself. The Solr class has the Solr server's IP address and login credentials, likewise does the MySQL class, etc. Also, we have a few options that we pass into the fourth PDO parameter and it is much cleaner to see `$pdo = new Pdo_Wrapper()` then 12 or so lines of code everywhere it is used. This is especially true if you are using autoloading for your classes.

Comment: Ok if you want a connection manager for PDO - so be it. Don't call it wrapper.

Answer (score 0):

Change this line

```
while($line = $DB->resultset()) {
```

to

```
foreach($DB->resultset() as $line ) {
```